Can Bicep Output API Management Service TXT Record Value?
I'm setting up Bicep for APIM and need to output the TXT record value after deployment, similar to how it's done for App Services. Currently, when I run the deployment, it throws an error that includes the TXT record value, but I haven't found an alternative method to retrieve this value. Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Document I'm referencing- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
Output Example:
output hostname string = publicIP.properties.dnsSettings.fqdn
Example of the code I've tried.
resource apiManagementService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2022-08-01' = {
  name: string
  location: string
  tags: string
  sku: {
    name: string
    capacity: int
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: string
    publisherName: string
    hostnameConfigurations: [
    {
      certificateSource: 'Managed'
      defaultSslBinding: true
      hostName: 'exampleHostName'
      negotiateClientCertificate: false
      type: 'Proxy'
    }
  ]
  }
}


Can you share the code trying so far? @Sheleby

@Jahnavi I've added the example code and the document I'm following to the main post. The bicep overall works great, I'm just wondering if there is a way to output the TXT record value at the end of the deployment instead of retrieving it from the error message. Please let me know if you have any question, thanks!

@Sheleby
I passed the output using: resource.properties.hostnameConfigurations[0].hostName
Here is my bicep sample :
resource apiManagementService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2022-08-01' = {
  name: 'uniqueAPIMName'
  location: 'West US'
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: 'email@example.com'
    publisherName: 'Publisher Name'
  }
}

output txtRecord string = apiManagementService.properties.hostnameConfigurations[0].hostName


cli result snipets:
 az deployment group create --resource-group demo --template-file apim2.bicep
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/apim2",
  "location": null,
  "name": "apim2",
  "properties": {
    "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "debugSetting": null,
    "dependencies": [],
    "duration": "PT2.2502284S",
    "error": null,
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "onErrorDeployment": null,
    "outputResources": [
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/uniqueAPIMName",
        "resourceGroup": "demo"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "txtRecord": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "uniqueapimname.azure-api.net"
      }
    },
    "parameters": null,
    "parametersLink": null,
    "providers": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "namespace": "Microsoft.ApiManagement",
        "providerAuthorizationConsentState": null,
        "registrationPolicy": null,
        "registrationState": null,
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiProfiles": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "defaultApiVersion": null,
            "locationMappings": null,
            "locations": [
              "westus"
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "service",
            "zoneMappings": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "templateHash": "1xxxxxxxx",
    "templateLink": null,
    "timestamp": "2024-07-31T22:27:54.697568+00:00",
    "validatedResources": null
  },
  "resourceGroup": "demo",
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
}


Thank you for your response! I will give this a try on my code and see what the results are. Do you think this same concept could work to retrieve the domain ownership identifier for APIM?

@Sheleby did you give this a try.
